# Regex to match a numeric token, but only if not part of another word

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# Regex I'm trying to match a token which contains the `@` symbol. For instance:

> Your salary is @1 for this month.

I can't use a pattern like `\b@1\b` because `\b` matches the beginning and ending of a word and `@1` is correctly not recognised as a word.

What pattern can I use to match tokens like this i.e `@1`, `@2` etc?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what rules you want applied, but perhaps something along the lines of `(^|\s)@\d\b` is what you are after?  Or perhaps `\W` instead of `\s`?  Again, it's not clear exactly what your intentions are.

Comment: How are your *tokens* delimited? By whitespace? Punctuation? etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use look-arounds `(?<!\w)` (=no word character allowed right before) and `(?!\w)` (=no word character allowed right after).

```
(?<!\w)@\d+(?!\w)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Cw)%40%5Cd%2B(%3F!%5Cw)&i=Your%20salary%20is%20%401%20for%20this%20month.)

Note that `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.